# Php, SimpleXMLIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to understand a small part of a code I am studying,
This is the [Link](http://pastebin.com/7ixuQWG3) to the code, the part i did not understand is this:

```
new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, 1)
```

What I didn't understand about this part is the second parameter, I tried to play with the value of this parameter and I assume it's about the XML structure but the logic with it is a bit odd, So if anyone can please clarify to me about this second parameter?

Comment: One reason to not put the example-code into links (to pastebins etc.) is because it can easily get lost. Your question is now not clear any longer. Please add it again - but to the question and the part you actually ask about (not a 100+ line script, just the example code that ships the context of your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok let me break it down

What you need to first understand is this line :

```
 $it = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, 'SimpleXMLIterator');
```

From PHP DOC

> You may use this optional parameter so that simplexml_load_string() will return an object of the specified class.

This means that all output would use `SimpleXMLIterator` and the best way to iterate is using `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

`Recursion` is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way. [See wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Example

```
$xml = '
<movies>
  <movie>abcd</movie>
  <movie>efgh</movie>
  <movie>
    <name> Test </name>
    <type> Action </type>   
    </movie>    
</movies>';


echo "<pre>" ;
echo "With Just SimpleXmlIterator\n";

foreach (new SimpleXmlIterator($xml) as $value ) {
    print($value . PHP_EOL);
}


echo "<pre>" ;
echo " RecursiveIteratorIterator \n";

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator  (new SimpleXmlIterator($xml)) as $value ) {
    print(trim($value) . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Output 1

```
With Just SimpleXmlIterator
abcd
efgh
```

Output 2

```
RecursiveIteratorIterator 
abcd
efgh
Test
Action
```

Comment: Thank you Baba for your replay, If i got it right the RecursiveIteratorIterator constructor is taking the object i assume the object is converted to an array, Then it iterator all the values witin the Recursive Array?...

Answer (score 3):

You should read the documentation for the [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php).  Reproducing the relevant portion here:

Optional **mode**. Possible values are

- **RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY** - The default. Lists only leaves in iteration.
- **RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST** - Lists leaves and parents in iteration with parents coming first.
- **RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST** - Lists leaves and parents in iteration with leaves coming first.

Comment: I think i got it about the second parameter thank you Sean Bright.